# Redirect Subdomain URL to another SubDomain in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, redirect, http-redirect

I need to redirect a "fake" sub domain to a real subdomain in IIS 7.5. The reason is that the marketing department doesn't want to use the actual website address in print pieces.

**Actual site URL:**

reporting.usapartners.com

**Marketing dept wants**
report.usapartners.com (fake) to **redirect to** reporting.usapartners.com (real)

Again, report.usapartners.com does not exist, only reporting.usapartners.com exists

**Here is what I tried**

I added a binding in IIS, for the site reporting.usapartners.com. I added report.usapartners.com as the host name and used the reporting.usapartners.com IP address

Then I went into reporting.usapartners.com web.config and added this:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="report" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="report.usapartners.com" negate="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://reporting.usapartners.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Looks like my solution creates an alias that cannot be redirected to.

Am I even approaching this problem correctly? Seems like it should be a simple problem to solve but perhaps not? Any ideas are welcomed and appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am just curious, why not just add another binding. One site can have multiple host names. As long as no ssl is involved, it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to create a separate site with host bindings for `report.usapartners.com` (the fake site) in IIS. This is going to be a stub site (it will still need a path on the disk, but it's only going to have a `web.config` in there) which will just host a redirect rule.

Now click on `HTTP Redirect` for that site in IIS and tick `Redirect requests to this destination` and put `http://reporting.usapartners.com` in the textbox. Then tick `Redirect all requests to exact destination (instead of relative to destination)`, don’t tick the next one and then choose Status Code `Permanent (301)`.

If you want it to redirect and keep the subdirectories and/or query string, then you can change the contents of the textbox to be `http://reporting.usapartners.com$S$Q`. Note that there is no trailing slash in this case. The `$S` preserves the sub directories and the `$Q` preserves the query string.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. Thought there might be an easier way. Thanks

Comment: I will try it but I've done that before and it always works but it's kinda alot of work but at least it works

Answer (score 5):

Your rule is causing a redirect loop.

Observe what your rule does:

- Match any given URL (this includes "/", "/something", "/something/another.html", etc.)
- If the host name ISN'T "report.usapartners.com"
- Redirect permanently the request to "http://reporting.usapartners.com"

So, as you see, as soon as the user is redirected to the reporting subdomain, it gets redirected again to reporting, because hostname isn't "report.usapartners.com".

<strike>The key here is the `negate="true"` attribute on the rule condition. Remove it or set it to false and you are good to go.</strike>

**Edit:**

You are almost there.

The real solution would be to change the host name on the rule to the desired host, keeping the negate true, so your rule would do:

- Match any given URL (this includes "/", "/something", "/something/another.html", etc.)
- If the host name ISN'T **"reporting.usapartners.com"**
- Redirect permanently the request to "http://reporting.usapartners.com"

Code:

```
...
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="reporting.usapartners.com" negate="true" />
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed that but I would suspect that would cause a browser redirection error. Still getting the 500 without: <match url="(.*)"  ignoreCase="true" />