# redirect subdomains from one domain to another domain's subdomain in iis with url rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, .net-core

I want to redirect subdomains that come to iis to subdomains in localhost:port that my dotnet core application is running.

---

Simply i want to redirect like this:

xyz.example.com => xyz.localhost:4000

john.example.com => john.localhost:4000

test.example.com => test.localhost:4000

example.com => localhost:4000 (no subdomain address redirects to localhost:4000)

---

How can I do this with url rewrite rules is iis?

---

## Edit:

there are some solutions for one subdomain (like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082219/redirect-subdomain-url-to-another-subdomain-in-iis)) but my question is more general to redirect all subdomain from one domain to corresponding subdomain in another domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect Subdomain URL to another SubDomain in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082219/redirect-subdomain-url-to-another-subdomain-in-iis)

Comment: No, this is not duplicate, because that question that you mentioned is very simpler than my problem. I need dynamically rewrite all subdomains, not only samples I wrote.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the rule that performs redirect you are asking for:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Test Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^((.+.)?)example.com" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}localhost:4000{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It's pretty straightforward:

1. `<match url=".*" />` matches any URL. Whether requested URL is in `example.com` domain is checked in later condition. `match` section is useless for our case because it operates with the URL part without a hostname (after first '/').
2. Condition `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^((.+.)?)example.com" />` matches domains like `xyz.example.com` or `example.com`. If condition is matched, capture group `{C:1}` will contain `xyz.` for `xyz.example.com` and empty string for `example.com`, which will be used further.
3. `<action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}localhost:4000{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />`

   The result URL is built as `http://{C:1}localhost:4000{REQUEST_URI}`. `{C:1}` will hold subdomain name as said above and `{REQUEST_URI}` contains URL part after hostname. We also set `appendQueryString` to `false` because query is a part of `{REQUEST_URI}`.

You should add this `<rewrite>` section to site `web.config` under `<system.webServer>`. You could also configure it manually from IIS Configuration Manager. Here is a screenshot of such configuration:

[image]

Finally, here is a set of test that demonstrates how urls are changed:

```
[TestCase("http://xyz.example.com", "http://xyz.localhost:4000/")]
[TestCase("http://xyz.example.com/some/inner/path", "http://xyz.localhost:4000/some/inner/path")]
[TestCase("http://xyz.example.com/some/inner/path?param1=value1&param2=value2", "http://xyz.localhost:4000/some/inner/path?param1=value1&param2=value2")]
[TestCase("http://example.com", "http://localhost:4000/")]
[TestCase("http://example.com/some/inner/path", "http://localhost:4000/some/inner/path")]
[TestCase("http://example.com/some/inner/path?param1=value1&param2=value2", "http://localhost:4000/some/inner/path?param1=value1&param2=value2")]
public void CheckUrlRedirect(string originalUrl, string expectedRedirectUrl)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false}))
    {
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(originalUrl).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently, response.StatusCode);
        var redirectUrl = response.Headers.Location.ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedRedirectUrl, redirectUrl);
    }
}
```